# Passando sql em indice de array CAKEPHP

Tags: sql, array, cakephp

Preciso fazer 3 consultas, se ícone x estiver habilitado, faça consulta X. Se for o ícone y, consulta y. Se os 2 estiverem, quero tudo da consulta x e y.

Eu consigo obter a consulta x e y, mas na hora de obter tudo das 2 consultas não consigo.

Ifs para verificar os itens.

```
 if(in_array('pacote',$criterios_pesquisa) && in_array('curso',$criterios_pesquisa)){
        $criterios['Curso.pacote '] = ? ;
    }
        if(in_array('pacote',$criterios_pesquisa)){
            $criterios['Curso.pacote'] = 1;
        }
        if(in_array('curso',$criterios_pesquisa)){
            $criterios['Curso.pacote !='] = 1;
        }
```

No meu banco de dados os pacotes podem ser 1 ou 0, como vcs veem isso foi feito, ou pega `pacote = 1` ou `pacote != 1`, estou tendo dificuldade para pegar os 2.

@edit

Fiz dessa maneira e consegui resolver, se alguém tiver algum método mais 'bonito', fique a vontade.

```
if(in_array('pacote',$criterios_pesquisa)){
            $criterios['Curso.pacote'] = 1;
        }
        if(in_array('curso',$criterios_pesquisa)){
            $criterios['Curso.pacote !='] = 1;
        }
        if(in_array('pacote',$criterios_pesquisa) && in_array('curso',$criterios_pesquisa)){
            unset($criterios['Curso.pacote']);
            unset($criterios['Curso.pacote !=']);
        }
```

Comment: Uma outra forma seria: **https://ideone.com/dZR0Mf**, não sei como está a sua *array* `criterios_pesquisa`, portanto não sei se irá funcionar para você.